# Getting card funding parameter from Stripe Android API

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I an using [the Stripe Android API](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android) to process payments in a mobile application. When a user registers for the app, a Stripe token is generated based on their credit card information. As per the requirement of the project, the app needs to reject prepaid credit cards from being used. Unfortunately, the Android API does not give access to the `funding` parameter of the `Card` object returned from the stripe token. This parameter states weather the card is prepaid, debit or credit.

Does anyone know how to access this information on Android? If this is not possible using the Stripe Android API, is there anyway I can directly access the JSON object returned from the Stripe API?

Answer (score 3):

The [Stripe Android bindings](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android) do not directly expose the [card object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/curl#card_object) from the API (which has the `funding` attribute you're interested in), but you can retrieve it by the token ID using the [Java bindings](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java). Something like this should work:

```
public void onSuccess(Token token) {
    com.stripe.model.Token stripeToken = com.stripe.model.Token.retrieve(token.getId(), publishableKey);
    com.stripe.model.Card stripeCard = stripeToken.getCard();
    if (stripeCard.getFunding().equals("prepaid") {
        // Reject card
    }
}
```

Note that this is basically what the Android bindings do when creating the token in the first place (see [here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/blob/master/stripe/src/main/java/com/stripe/android/Stripe.java#L25)).

EDIT: After investigating a bit further, I'm not so sure the above will work. While there is a `requestToken()` method in the Android bindings that calls the [retrieve token](https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_token) API with the publishable key (see [here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/blob/master/stripe/src/main/java/com/stripe/android/Stripe.java#L52)), I don't think it actually works. Calling this endpoint with a publishable key results in an error indicating that the secret key should be used. (I guess it was an undocumented behavior that was removed at some point.)

If this is the case, then I guess you have two options:

- patch the Android bindings to make the `funding` property from the API object available in the Android object (at creation time), or
- make the check server-side.

Comment: Could this be used along side the Android bindings or would I need to use the Java bindings exclusively?

Comment: You should be able to use the two. As far as I can tell, the Java bindings are a dependency of the Android bindings anyway!

Comment: Thanks for the update. I tried to use this method but encountered the error you described in your edit. At this point I will just do the check server-side.

Answer (score 0):

What about this? I used Ywain answer and put it into Async like Stripe SDK do. Works for me.

```
private class CreateStripeTokenTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, com.stripe.model.Token> {

    private Map<String, Object> mMap;
    protected CreateStripeTokenTask(Card card) {
        mMap = hashMapFromCard(card);
    }

    @Override
    protected com.stripe.model.Token doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try
        {
            RequestOptions requestOptions = RequestOptions.builder().setApiKey(<YOUR_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY>).build();
            com.stripe.model.Token stripeToken = com.stripe.model.Token.create(mMap, requestOptions);
            return stripeToken;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(com.stripe.model.Token stripeToken) {
        if (stripeToken != null && stripeToken.getCard() != null)
        {
            if ("prepaid".equals(stripeToken.getCard().getFunding()))
            {
                //error - prepaid cards are not eligible

            }
            else
            {
                //card is fine
            }
        }
    }

    private Map<String, Object> hashMapFromCard(Card card) {
        Map<String, Object> tokenParams = new HashMap<>();

        Map<String, Object> cardParams = new HashMap<>();
        cardParams.put("number", TextUtils.nullIfBlank(card.getNumber()));
        cardParams.put("cvc", TextUtils.nullIfBlank(card.getCVC()));
        cardParams.put("exp_month", card.getExpMonth());
        cardParams.put("exp_year", card.getExpYear());
        cardParams.put("name", TextUtils.nullIfBlank(card.getName()));
        cardParams.put("currency", TextUtils.nullIfBlank(card.getCurrency()));
        cardParams.put("address_line1", TextUtils.nullIfBlank(card.getAddressLine1()));
        cardParams.put("address_line2", TextUtils.nullIfBlank(card.getAddressLine2()));
        cardParams.put("address_city", TextUtils.nullIfBlank(card.getAddressCity()));
        cardParams.put("address_zip", TextUtils.nullIfBlank(card.getAddressZip()));
        cardParams.put("address_state", TextUtils.nullIfBlank(card.getAddressState()));
        cardParams.put("address_country", TextUtils.nullIfBlank(card.getAddressCountry()));

        // Remove all null values; they cause validation errors
        for (String key : new HashSet<>(cardParams.keySet())) {
            if (cardParams.get(key) == null) {
                cardParams.remove(key);
            }
        }

        tokenParams.put("card", cardParams);
        return tokenParams;
    }
}
```